# cmake keeps adding the std=gnu++11 option

Tags: macos, gcc, cmake, std

I'm trying to compile a project in **C++** using `cmake`, and in the page of the project they tell me that it will crash if I don't add the standard 98. (I'm on a mac)
I've tried all I found on the internet and I could manage to make the `cmake` use the option `-std=c++98` but it also adds `-DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11`.  (I saw it using the make `VERBOSE=1` option)

I would like to get rid of that. Using the `--trace` option I could see that the option is set in a file which is in the cellar folder, that is, is something that has to do with `cmake` itself and not in the `CMakeList.txt` file im using.

How can I solve this problem?

If it can help the code I'm trying to compile is this:
[SAMoS](https://github.com/sknepneklab/SAMoS)

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

with the `--trace` option I was able to see that the `-std=gnu++11` option was selected in the file:

`/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.9.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/Compiler/GNU-CXX.cmake`
which can be seen here [GNU-CXX.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/GNU-CXX.cmake)

If I eddit that file in a way that every if sets the option to `-std=c++98` then, the cmake complains giving me the next error:

> CMake Error in src/CMakeLists.txt:
>
> The compiler feature "cxx_nullptr" is not known to CXX compiler
>
> "GNU"
>
> version 7.2.0.

I don't know what else can I try...

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)`

Comment: If I use that is when I get the two options at the same time

Comment: Something else is likely setting `-std=gnu11`, perhaps a transitive dependency. Try using [`variable_watch`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html) on each of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`. (eg: `variable_watch(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)`), and take note of where these variables change

Comment: whith the variable_watch I can see that there are no more changes to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. However with the `--trace` I was able to see where it was being changed. I added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion of VTK is polluting SAMoS's CMake scope with the C++11 requirement. You can test this by disabling VTK on your `cmake` command line.

```
$ cd ~SAMoS
$ mkdir build; cd build
$ cmake -DVTK_FOUND=FALSE ../
[...]
$ make VERBOSE=1
[...]
Scanning dependencies of target samos
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f src/CMakeFiles/samos.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/samos.dir/build
[  1%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/samos.dir/samos.cpp.o
cd /Users/nega/SAMoS/build/src && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -DCGAL_USE_GMP -DCGAL_USE_MPFR -DHAS_CGAL -isystem /usr/local/include -I/include -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/constraints -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/dump -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/log -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/integrators -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/messenger -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/parser -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/potentials -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/potentials/external -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/potentials/pair -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/potentials/bond -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/potentials/angle -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/system -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/utils -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/aligner -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/aligner/pair -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/aligner/external -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src/population -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/src -I/Users/nega/SAMoS/build  -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/samos.dir/samos.cpp.o -c /Users/nega/SAMoS/src/samos.cpp
```

You'll notice there's no `-std=gnu++11` flag anymore. Of course, since it looks like you're GCC version 7.2, you'll still want your set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` to `98` since gcc-7.2 uses C++11 by default. (Or maybe it's C++14 now...) You can do this on your `cmake` command line.

```
$ cmake -DUSE_VTK=FALSE -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=98 ..
```

CMake will then add `-std=gnu++98` to its compile commands.

If you can't live without VTK, then you'll need to send a bug report upstream asking the SAMoS folks to clarify their documentation, or fix how they're including VTK.

Answer (score 12):

You need to set the language standard:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)
```

Depending on the compiler, it may enable extensions as well. To disable the GNU extensions also add:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

Note that setting this options does so only for the specified target and dependent targets.

Have take a look at [this section](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#manual:cmake-compile-features(7)) of the CMake manual for more information on compiler features. Do note however, using this

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tryed that and it is the first time that something happens to the `std=gnu++11` option. Now it has chaged to c++, that is, now it uses two options at the same time `std=c++98` and `std=c++11`. I still cant get rid of the standard 11 :(

Comment: You will need to provide more information on the code you are trying to compile for us to help you. I would start by grepping for c++11.

Comment: Using the `--trace` option from make i could see that the file that sets the `std=gnu++11` option is not in the project but in the cmake installation folder

Comment: Just setting the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` doesn't seem enough to get the specified standard. Is there a module to include as well?

Comment: No, it’s part of CMake itself. `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` does indeed set the standard for the target and all following targets. It will not add it to targets project-wide only when specified. You may also try using `target_compile_features(mylib PUBLIC cxx_std_11)`